# Full screen window command from Linux terminal?

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, window

On Cinnamon, you can [set a hotkey](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-change-the-linux-mint-cinnamon-keyboard-shortcuts-4064754) to force the active window into full screen mode; many programs have a full screen toggle built in. What I'm wondering is, what's the command that's being sent? How would you issue such a command in a terminal emulator to resize an application window so that it includes the space occupied by taskbars/panels?

Comment: It's setting the _NET_WM_STATE_FULLSCREEN atom on the window.

Comment: Have a look at `wmctrl`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on @dirkt's comment I went and had a look at `wmctrl`, which is a command line tool that lets you set these yourself. If you'd like to do things like toggle fullscreen for whatever programs you like from a shell script or any other custom place, this is ideal for that.

Here's an example that toggles fullscreen for the currently active window:

```
wmctrl -r ':ACTIVE:' -b toggle,fullscreen
```

For more details on what you can do with this see [the man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wmctrl) and for some example see [this tutorial](https://www.linuxjournal.com/magazine/hack-and-automate-your-desktop-wmctrl).